# Creating TableLayout and calling it from another class - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, tablelayout

I am creating a database in my DatabaseHelper class.  I created the textview, tablerows and tablelayout in this class.  I also added the textviews to the tablerows and the tablerows to the tablelayout.

My question is how to call this tablelayout from another class and display it in the activity.  I researched a little bit and it seems they want me to write the line of code I have commented out below.  From the line that is commented out, it doesn't seem like I can implement that because this class does not have an activity/xml file.

Hopefully I explained that well enough.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

    Context context;    
    DatabaseHelper dh;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; 
    private static final String DB_NAME = "test3"; 
    private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.test/databases/";
    private static final String TABLE = "HighscoresList"; 

    // Table columns names. 
    private static final String RANK = "_id"; 
    private static final String SCORE = "score"; 
    private static final String PERCENTAGE = "percentage";

    TableLayout table;
    TableRow rowHeader, row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9, row10;
    TextView rank, percentage, score;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) { 
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
        db = getWritableDatabase();

        TableRow rowHeader = new TableRow(context);
        TableRow row1 = new TableRow(context);
        TableRow row2 = new TableRow(context);
        TableRow row3 = new TableRow(context);
        TableRow row4 = new TableRow(context);
        TableRow row5 = new TableRow(context);
        TableRow row6 = new TableRow(context);
        TableRow row7 = new TableRow(context);
        TableRow row8 = new TableRow(context);
        TableRow row9 = new TableRow(context);
        TableRow row10 = new TableRow(context);

        TextView rank = new TextView(context);
        TextView percentage = new TextView(context);
        TextView score = new TextView(context);
        TextView r1r = new TextView(context);
        TextView r1p = new TextView(context);
        TextView r1s = new TextView(context);

        Cursor c_percentage = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + PERCENTAGE + " FROM " + TABLE + ";", null);
        Cursor c_score = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + SCORE + " FROM " + TABLE + ";", null);

        rank.setText("TEST - COLUMN RANK");
        percentage.setText("TEST - COLUMN PERCENTAGE");
        score.setText("TEST - COLUMN SCORE");
        r1r.setText("test..rank");
        r1p.setText("teset...percentage");
        r1s.setText("test...scoree");

        rowHeader.addView(rank);
        rowHeader.addView(percentage);
        rowHeader.addView(score);

        row1.addView(r1r);
        row1.addView(r1p);
        row1.addView(r1s);

        table.addView(rowHeader);
        table.addView(row1);
        table.addView(row2);
        table.addView(row3);
        table.addView(row4);
        table.addView(row5);
        table.addView(row6);
        table.addView(row7);
        table.addView(row8);
        table.addView(row9);
        table.addView(row10); 

              //table = (TableLayout)contextActivity.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    }

          //more methods and code below...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You TableLayout is a View, and should only be used (for display) in an Activity. So put all the code relating to your TableLayout in the activity in which you want to display this table. Use your DatabaseHelper class (as its name suggests) only for help in accessing the Database. As such:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper dh;

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; 
    private static final String DB_NAME = "test3"; 
    private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.test/databases/";
    private static final String TABLE = "HighscoresList"; 

    // Table columns names. 
    private static final String RANK = "_id"; 
    private static final String SCORE = "score"; 
    private static final String PERCENTAGE = "percentage";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) { 
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDb() {
      return this.getReadableDatabase(); // Use Readable because you're not actually writing any values into your db
    }

    public void closeDb(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.close();
    }

    public Cursor getScore(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      return db.rawQuery("SELECT " + SCORE + " FROM " + TABLE + ";", null);
    }

    public Cursor getPercentage(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      return db.rawQuery("SELECT " + PERCENTAGE + " FROM " + TABLE + ";", null);
    }
}
```

Now from your activity you can do something like:

```
public class Blah extends Activity {
  ...
  public void drawTable() {
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    ... // initialize all views as before
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.openDb();

    Cursor scores = helper.getScore(db);
    Cursor percentages = helper.getPercentage(db);
    ... // do something with the Cursors
    ..
    // finally
    scores.close();
    percentages.close();
    helper.closeDb(db);
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Code structure, what goes in each class and how many classes are needed is probably the hardest thing I deal with in most projects.  I will go implement your advice.  Thanks!